# Find more than three columns having equal value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple columns have equal value. I want to find the row id which have more than 3 columns have equal value.

```
@each column is text/blob
```

Table structure is like -

```
id  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9
```

Comment: Maybe see normalisation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Unpivot` the data and check for equality, Try this trick.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM   (SELECT id,col1 AS col from Yourtable
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT id,col2  from Yourtable
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT id,col3  from Yourtable
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT id,col4  from Yourtable
        Union ALL
        .......) A 
GROUP  BY id,col 
HAVING Count(1) > 3
```