# Find equal values in 2 datetime columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am trying to compare 2 datetime columns in SQL to find the rows with matching datetime values in both columns (`StartDate` & `EndDate`).

I tried the solution in [Find more than three columns having equal value in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237438/find-more-than-three-columns-having-equal-value-in-mysql) but I keep getting incorrect syntax errors when I enter my `id`, `col1` and `Yourtable` items. Mostly regarding the pre-final part of the query: `.....) A`

Does anyone know another better solution to find the rows with equal values in the columns `StartDate` and `EndDate`?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: You didn't copy it along with the "...." part, did you?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, please put some data here or atleast your sample SQL query if you need help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going for the obvious here.

```
SELECT 
  * --Or Key Columns
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE 
    StartDate = EndDate;
```